# How create an installer of chrome packaged app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I need to demonstrate a test version of my app. I DON'T want to load it to the store yet. I want create an installer of my app, so the user can go to my site and install the application by clicking.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, have you read the documentation including [developer installation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html#unpacked), [enterprise installation](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453), [publishing on the Web Store only to test accounts](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish#testaccounts), and [recent announcements of changes](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html)? Assuming you have, then with the exceptions listed in those sources, all apps/extensions must be published in CWS. They don't have to be listed publicly, but they do have to be published there.

Your best bet is to use the test-account feature of CWS for your demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy, yo can create the installer vía chrome://extensions > Developer Mode > Package extension.
Then you got the .crx file, you can upload it anywhere and share it. To install it, user must open chrome//extensions and drop the file in the page.
The option to install from webpage by clicking was disabled in Chrome for security reasons.